# Custom bibliography style: Setting state variables in bst files

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am customizing the default *dinat.bst* file for customizing my bibliography style.

The file contains some state variables:

```
INTEGERS { output.state 
           before.all 
       mid.sentence 
       after.sentence 
       after.block
       colon.after 
       period.dash }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
% initialisation of the state variables
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence := 
  #3 'after.block :=
  #4 'colon.after :=
  #5 'period.dash :=
}

FUNCTION {set.period.dash}
% set ". -- "
{ output.state before.all =
    { skip$ }
    { period.dash 'output.state := }
  if$
}
```

But I am not really sure about the syntax.

How can I set these state variables?
If I want to use a period dash after every entry, for example - how do I need to adapt the function `set.period.dash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First important thing to know: The syntax of bst files is based on [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

After knowing this, I understood the syntax. The code extract which I posted in the question is just declaration and initialization of the init states.

If you want to customize a specific entry type, the right place for changes is further down in the *dinat.bst* file, where the entry types are defined.

E.g., I wanted to modify the `@MISC` type:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
% required: 
% optional: author, title, howpublished, month, year, note, url
{ out.bibitem.start
          ...
          url set.period.dash.check
          push.url out
          ...
  out.bibitem.end
}
```

Inside the entry specification the init states are used. In my case, I did not want to have a period and dash before an URL. So, I commented `url set.period.dash.check` out.

In order to get an period dash after every bibitem, I edited the function

```
FUNCTION {out.bibitem.end}
% end of entry
{ write$                    % add new.sentence or ".~" write$
  newline$
}
```

Comment: Some other bst files - different from dinat.bst - indeed have state variables in the top, which can be set to 0 or 1 for customizing the style.